# Disable text on tags in awesomeWM?

Tags: theme, awesome, lua

The current awesomewm theme that I am using has small icons to manage the tags, as opposed to the traditional numbers. How can I disable the numbers from displaying over top of my icons?

[image: current tag list]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question! Basically, each of those tags has a label in your `rc.lua` file (either in `/etc/xdg/awesome` or `$HOME/.config/awesome`), so you can rewrite those as you please. The default look of this line (around 86 in the default file) is something like

```
tags = {}
for s = 1, screen.count() do
    -- Each screen has its own tag table.
    tags[s] = awful.tag({ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" }, s, layouts[1])
end
```

To remove the labels on them all (and make them fit with my icons with a small buffer at the end), I replaced them all with whitespace:

```
tags = {}
for s = 1, screen.count() do
    -- Each screen has its own tag table.
    tags[s] = awful.tag({ "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "   " }, s, layouts[1])
end
```